# Can't access attached device on server using ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, iis, permissions, hardware

My ASP.NET app cannot access a device that is attached to the server. It says device does not exist. I have Changed user identity of the application pool to 'LocalSystem' and 'LocalService' but I'm getting the same error. Is there any special permission that I have to set for ASP.NET (or IIS) to get them access to the device?

The device is working properly from a desktop app running on the server.

**Full story**

I'm using 'Dermalog Finger Scanner' device to scan fingerprints on the client and send them to server to find a match. On the server I'm using 'FingerCode3' library (from Dermalog) to compare fingerprints. the library needs either a license or an actual fingerprint scanner device attached to PC to work. So I'm using a fingerprint scanner (Dermalog ZF1) as a license for the matcher library. and this is the error:

```
The license for the SDK is not valid (Check whether the DermalogLicenser or a DermalogLiveScanner is required for your product).
```

Comment: Did u find the solution?